# Visual studio 2015 nuget package not restoring

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

I've got a project with multiple nuget projects, when I opened this project with visual studio 2015 I did a nuget restore, but all packages references are still broken. In the packages folder, all the packages have been downloaded. How can I restore the packages? It is important that the versions currently defined stay the same and don't upgrade the packages.

[image]

If I unload my project, the references seem good, the package versions match:

```
<Reference Include="Dapper">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Dapper.1.42\lib\net45\Dapper.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="EasyNetQ">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EasyNetQ.0.49.3.390\lib\net40\EasyNetQ.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="FluentScheduler">
  <HintPath>..\packages\FluentScheduler.3.1.45\lib\net40\FluentScheduler.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

First navigate to C:\Users\.dnx\packages and delete all packages from this location.

Next, in VS2015 load your project and in the Package Manager Console run `dnu restore` (you may have to use the cd command to get into the same directory as your project.json file if it doesn't default you to there)

Comment: There are no path starting with .dnx in my Users folder.

Comment: "The term 'dnu' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" when I try in the Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

The .nuget folder was missing. For some sort of reason, committing my .nuget folder from the original solution to the projects SVN, and then updating the broken project SVN fixed the problem.